# Coalescing aggregate of fields in postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, coalesce

I'm trying to group by a `name` field, but with a 'coalescing aggregate' of the other values a row might have. Here's the data:

```
name        | jurisdiction    | db_from
------------|-----------------|----------------
my station    NULL              2017-06-21 8:01
my station    my jurisdiction   2017-06-21 8:00
my station    old data          2017-06-21 7:59
```

I want to wind up with:

```
name        | jurisdiction    
------------|-----------------
my station    my jurisdiction
```

Here's what I've come up with:

```
WITH _stations AS (
    SELECT * FROM config.stations x ORDER BY x.db_from DESC
)SELECT 
    x."name",
    (array_remove(array_agg(x.jurisdiction), NULL))[1] as jurisdiction
FROM _stations x
GROUP BY
    x."name";
```

Some of the values of the `jurisdiction` fields may be null and I'm trying to take the most recent one that's not null.

I know I shouldn't be relying on the order of the CTE, but it seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a bit if digging to find this so I hope it helps. Let me know if this isn't the best way to solve the problem:

```
SELECT 
    x."name",
    (array_remove(array_agg(x.jurisdiction ORDER BY x.db_from DESC), NULL))[1] as jurisdiction
FROM config.stations x
GROUP BY x."name"
```

Comment: I am having this same problem. I ended up with the exact same as you but I hate it! I really hate it. I have a real lack of trust in the data to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (x."name")
  *
from
  _stations x
where
  x.jurisdiction is not null
order by
  x."name", x.db_from desc
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Yeah, but I have multiple fields I'm looking for in the actual, production use case.